# OleDB Exception when trying to read directories

Tags: c#, winforms, casting, checkboxlist, listitem

I'm not able to solve my problem but I didn't find any solutions that match my case on the web. I have a CheckBoxList and simply want to get the Items which are checked into a list.

Code:

```
  foreach (ListItem item in checkedMonthsBox.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                months.Add(item);
            }
        }
```

I get a System.InvalidCastException and

> "The object of "System.String" can not be converted into
>   "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem".

The months List is from type "ListItem".

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it!

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedMonthsBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (checkedMonthsBox.GetItemCheckState(i) == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                months.Add(checkedMonthsBox.Items[i].ToString());
            }
         }
```

Comment: Your old code with `months.Add(item.ToString());` likely would have worked too.

Comment: He crashed while starting the loop in the first line.